# Computing a set of all subsets (power set)

Tags: set, ocaml

I am trying to get a function (given as a parameter a set) to return a set whose elements are all the subset formed from the main set.
Ex: {1;2;3} -> { {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3} }

But I don't exactly know how to make a module that lets me work with a set of sets. What type should I define it as?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A set of all subsets is called a [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). To implement an algorithm you don't really need a special data structure, as you can represent a set with a list. Correspondingly a set of sets would be a list of lists. E.g.,

> `let rec superset = function
>       | [] -> [[]]
>       | x :: xs -> 
>          let ps = superset xs in
>          ps @ List.map (fun ss -> x :: ss) ps`

And here is an example of usage:

```
superset [1;2;3];;
- : int list list = [[]; [1]; [2]; [2; 1]; [3]; [3; 1]; [3; 2]; [3; 2; 1]
```

If you want to use real sets, like Jeffrey suggested. Then we will need to adapt the algorithm a little bit, since Set module provides a little bit different interface.

> `module S = Set.Make(String)
>
>     module SS = Set.Make(S)
>     let superset xs = 
>       S.fold (fun x ps -> 
>           SS.fold (fun ss -> SS.add (S.add x ss)) ps ps) xs 
>              (SS.singleton S.empty)`

To run the algorithm and to print the result we need to transform it back to a list, since OCaml toplevel doesn't know how to print sets:

```
# superset (S.of_list ["1"; "2"; "3"]) |> SS.elements |> List.map S.elements;;
- : S.elt list list =
[[]; ["1"]; ["1"; "2"]; ["1"; "2"; "3"]; ["1"; "3"]; ["2"]; ["2"; "3"];
 ["3"]]
```

Now, we can generalize algorithm, so that it will work on any ordered type.

> `module Superset(T : Set.OrderedType) = struct
>       module S = Set.Make(T)
>
>       module SS = Set.Make(S)
>       let of_set xs = 
>         S.fold (fun x ps -> 
>             SS.fold (fun ss -> SS.add (S.add x ss)) ps ps) xs
>                (SS.singleton S.empty)
>     end`

Now we can run it:

```
# module Superset_of_strings = Superset(String);;
# open Superset_of_string;;  
# of_set (S.of_list ["1"; "2"; "3"]) |> SS.elements |> List.map S.elements;;
- : S.elt list list =
[[]; ["1"]; ["1"; "2"]; ["1"; "2"; "3"]; ["1"; "3"]; ["2"]; ["2"; "3"];
 ["3"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the standard `Set` module, you can work with sets of strings (say) and sets of sets of strings like this:

```
# module S = Set.Make(String);;
. . .
# module SS = Set.Make(S);;
. . .

# let s1 = S.singleton "abc";;
val s1 : S.t = <abstr>
# let ss1 = SS.singleton s1;;
val ss1 : SS.t = <abstr>
# List.map S.elements (SS.elements ss1);;
- : S.elt list list = [["abc"]]
```